# How to find community feedback sites for web design and user experience critiques?

Tags: usability, website-design, feedback, user-feedback, recommendations

One of the ways I improve my website design and good user usability skills is by looking at other people's critiques on websites. I used to like [Concept Feedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com) but it has closed down.

How do I find similar sites?

(Please don't tell me to Google it. I did. I am trying to post this question in an acceptable SE Q&A format)

Comment: I didn't know this type of service existed. Good question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I do on a daily basis is check out sites like: 
http://www.awwwards.com/ 
http://www.cssdesignawards.com/ 
These sites are updated daily and show trends on web technologies. Others vote on Design, Usability, Creativity and Content for each site and you are able to see what it is that people are working towards.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for actual critiques & reviews, not ratings and awards.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich There is also this site. This a comunity chat where others can talk about trends, and submit their websites for comments and reviews. http://www.uplabs.com/chat

Answer (score 0):

You can try

http://clueapp.com/

http://www.bounceapp.com/

http://www.reelapp.com/

all by [**Zurb**](http://zurb.com/), all of them free. They don't have a lot of users though, and quite probably you'll need to try their paid services if you want some real feedback.

Otherwise, try [**22 Web Design Critique Websites To Help get feedback**](http://www.underworldmagazines.com/22-web-design-critique-websites-to-help-get-feedback/), although most of the sites listed are dead, some are still alive.

And of course, as long as you follow the rules, some criticism can be obtained from [**Graphic Design Stack Exchange**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the urls. Actually I don't want to solicit feedback for my own stuff. I want to see what others have said about other sites. Concept Feedback did this perfectly. It's unfortunate the site is gone but also that there's no site even close to what it offered? Community shareable feedback.

Comment: if you check those URLs, you'll see you can see and interact with other people's designs, at least the Zurb ones. They also offer a tablet app for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

A bit left field, but have you seen [theuserisdrunk](http://theuserisdrunk.com/) before?

The idea being a website should be so simple, even a drunk person can use it with ease. There's some good advice there.